# Write a program that will read numbers from the keyboard into a 2-dimensional table

Tags: java, arrays

i'm new to the community and I was wondering if i could get some tips on this program i'm suppose to make. I'm not sure exactly on how i'm suppose to continue this besides creating an an array for a 3x5 table and defining other variables. I would appreciate the help greatly

Comment: Maybe start by read some tutos, this is basic ;)

Comment: Yeah i'm in beginning programming and i'm actually quite ashamed that I haven't been making some progress on this. My instructor goes way to fast for beginners, so I decided to try some tutorials on Youtube and other sites

Answer (score -1):

a short script for reading input from the user and populate a table cells, hope it will get you started and learn the java lang... you should its awesome

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 5;
    int [][] table = new int[rows][cols];

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < cols; j++){
            System.out.println("Enter value for cell[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
            int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
            table[i][j] = userInput;
        }

    }
}
```

NOTE: there isn't any input check and error handling at this example!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much my good sir. My previous code looked quite messy. Is it alright if i report back here if I have any questions?

Comment: Hello there Shahaf. once again, thank you for taking the time to help me out. i'm quite a beginner at this so please bare with me. I seem to be stuck on one part. i'm trying to call a method to fill th table, but it looks like thats already done with this demo you showed me when i ran it.

Comment: @TroyHarris what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I think I just found out the answer to my question, sorry about that